# Implementing Load Balancing in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to `implement` Load Balancing in Django using Round robin method. At First I created model where I kept all instances and a sequence of each instance.

My Model:

```
class Load_Balancing(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    instance = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sequence = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: I am sure there are better ways to do it but you could keep another table which keeps a counter variable. For every incoming request, you can serve the instance at which current counter is set to. After serving increment counter by 1 and save it. once counter reaches 4, it resets to 0 in round robin fashion

Comment: If this sounds like a way to go, let me know and I can show you a PoC for this in answer

Comment: yes, sounds good to me.@MohitC

Comment: can you send it in answer @MohitC ?

Comment: Posted, accept and upvote if it helps you.

Answer (score 7):

Don't try to implement load balancing on application level as it makes no sense. 
Your database would be bottleneck in your solution.

use proper HTTP server/reverse proxy most of them have well established load-balancing support for example: [nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-load-balancer/#choosing-a-load-balancing-method), [apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html)

Answer (score 2):

Unaware of your intentions with getting an instance in your view and doing whatever further operations with it, below could be a simple PoC to achieve this.

However I strongly recommend you to go with iklinac's solution and reconsider your architecture design.

You can create a model which serves as a counter for you.
Note that this can also be done using an inmemory persistent solution like `pickle` but I prefer doing this way.

Create a table which acts as a counter

```
class InstanceSq(models.Model):
    sequence_id = models.IntegerField()
```

Table for this model will always only contain 1 row.

Get it in your views.py as below:

```
try:
    sequence_id = InstanceSq.objects.get(id=1).sequence_id
except InstanceSq.DoesNotExist:
    #This is when it runs first time
    instance_row = InstanceSq(sequence_id = 1)
    instance_row.save()
    sequence_id = 1

#..
#Here you get the current instance as:
instance_ip = Load_Balancing.objects.filter(sequence=sequence_id)
#Use your instance here and do whatever you want to do
#.. and then
# Rotation logic
new_id = sequence_id % 4 + 1
current = InstanceSq.objects.select_for_update().get(id=1) #to avoid race conditions
current.sequence_id = new_id
current.save()
```

Comment: This would generate race conditions on update, other thing is that ugly logic could be replaced with modulo ->  new_id = sequence_id % 4 + 1.

It has flaws but i up-voted it still for effort

Comment: @iklinac, Thanks, updated with your rotation logic. And using `update` will not generate any race condtions, you can verify it from django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update

Comment: let me explain, you are getting the object prior to updating it, lets asume multiple concurrent users. they will all get id of lets say 3 and try to update it to 4. One of ways to mitigate following would be using select_for_update